# I want to know how I extract word in sentence using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I use a regular expression in java.

i want to extract word which I want.

Example) `String exam = "..aa.aaa..bb.."`

i want to extract `"..aa.aaa.."` not `"..aa.aaa..bb.."`

So I try to regular expression like this `"(\\.\\.[a-z])([a-z]\\.\\.)"`

but,program return sentence `"..aa.aaa..bb.."`

what should I do?

==================================================================
this is full source

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws java.io.IOException {       

        String regex = "(\\.\\.[a-zA-Z0-9])[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]+{2,}.*([a-z]{2,}\\.\\.)";

        String useStr = "..aa.aaa..bb..";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(useStr);
        while (match.find()) {          
            String a = useStr.substring(match.start(), match.end());        
            System.out.println(a);          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The rule what to extract is not precisely explained / defined in your question. Hence we have to guess. Are you in search of the substring demarcated by the first two `..` or in the substring containing only `a` and `.`?

Comment: I'm yet to read a regular expression question that actually defines in unambiguous terms what is sought. Perhaps that's the root of all these problems - that very fact is not understood by the person asking the question.

Comment: I recommend that you first read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed parentheses around the `[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]+{2,}.*` in the middle and captured it into group 2 and then concatenated the first group and second group into String a.

I'm not sure if this is the exact *pattern* you wanted, but it's the right string.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String ar[]) throws java.io.IOException {       

        String regex = "(\\.\\.[a-zA-Z0-9])([^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]+{2,}.*)([a-z]{2,}\\.\\.)";

        String useStr = "..aa.aaa..bb..";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        Matcher match = pattern.matcher(useStr);
        while (match.find()) {          
            //String a = useStr.substring(match.start(), match.end());   
            String a = match.group(1) + match.group(2);  
            System.out.println(a);          
        }
    }
}
```

This sets `a` to and subsequently prints out: `..aa.aaa..`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for both regex I mentioned in the comment. The `firstTwoDots` matches the substring demarcated by the first two occurrences of `..` while the `dotsAndAs` matches everything composed of `.` and `a`:

```
public static void main(String ar[]) {       
    String firstTwoDots = "([.]{2})(.*?)([.]{2}).*";
    String dotsAndAs = "([.a]*).*";

    String useStr = "..aa.aaa..bb..";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(firstTwoDots).matcher(useStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + matcher.group(2) + matcher.group(3));

    matcher = Pattern.compile(dotsAndAs).matcher(useStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```